# MYSQL - Get a COUNT of rows from table 1 based on average of column in table 2

Tags: mysql

Hopefully somebody can help with this - had me stumped all afternoon.

I have 2 tables:

```
products - id | name | active
```

```
product_reviews - id | product_id | rating
```

The product_reviews contains multiple rows, each one containing a rating of the parent product.

What I'm trying to do is obtain a COUNT of all the products for each rating, for example:

- Rating 1 or above - 50 products
- Rating 2 or above - 40 products
- Rating 3 or above - 30 products
- Rating 4 or above - 20 products
- Rating 5 - 10 products

So far I have tried WHERE, SUBQUERY, HAVING and get inconsistent results, the closest I've got so far is:

```
SELECT products.id FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `product_reviews` ON `product_reviews`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
WHERE `products`.`active` = '1' 
HAVING (AVG(product_reviews.rating) > 1)
```

...and then counting the results, but these do not seem to be correct, obviously if I use COUNT(products.id) it will say 'incorrect use of aggregate'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query to get the number of products which are greater than or equal to one.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_reviews.product_id) 
FROM `product_reviews` 
INNER JOIN `products` 
  ON `product_reviews`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
WHERE `products`.`active` = '1'
  AND `product_reviews`.`rating` >= 1
```

But you have to run the query 5 times to get products for  different review groups

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this will get me a count of how many reviews each product has for each rating? What I'm trying to achieve is a count of how many products exist for each rating based on the aggregate review rating. For example, if product 1 has 5 reviews that aggregate 4 starts it will count as '1' under the 4 star count.